# Please Tell Me Where I Am Making A Mistake

Tags: java

```
   import java.util.Scanner;


   public class Addition
        {
        public Addition (int x , int y)
        {
         int sum;
         int one = x;
         int two = y;
         sum =x+y;
         System.out.println("Addition of Number:%d" +sum);
         }
         }

         public class Subtraction{
         public  Subtraction(int x ,int y){
         int sub;
         int one = x;
         int two = y;
         sub =x-y;
         System.out.println("Subtraction of Number: %d" +sub);
         }
         }
         public class Multiplication
         {
               public  Multiplication(int x ,int y){
          int mul;
          int one = x;
          int two = y;
          mul =x*y;
          System.out.println("Multiplication of Numbers:%d" +mul);
          }
          } 
          public class Division{
          public  Division(int x , int y){
          int div;
          int one = x;
          int two = y;
          div = x/y;
          }
          }
               public class Calculator
               {
               public static void main(String args[]){
               int one;
               int two;
               String choice;
               System.out.println("Enter numbers to calculate:");
               Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
               int one =input.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Your First Number =" +one);
               int two=input.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Your First Number =" +one);
               System.out.println("Enter your choice");
               String choice = input.nextLine();

               switch(choice){
               case Add:      
               Addition A =new Addition(int one ; int two); 
               break;
               case Sub:      
               Subtraction s =new Subtraction(int one; int two); 
               break;
               case Mul:      
               Multiplication m =new Multiplication(int one; int two); 
               break;
               case Div:      
               Division A =new Division(int one; int two); 
               break;
               default:
               System.out.println("Wrong Choice"); 
               break;
                       }
             }
       }
```

where i am doing mistake tell me
errors:

```
Calculator.java:55: error: '.class' expected
     Addition a =new Addition(int one ; int two); 
                                  ^
Calculator.java:55: error: ';' expected
     Addition a =new Addition(int one ; int two); 
                                               ^
Calculator.java:58: error: '.class' expected
     Subtraction s =new Subtraction(int one; int two); 
                                        ^
Calculator.java:58: error: ';' expected
     Subtraction s =new Subtraction(int one; int two); 
                                                    ^
Calculator.java:61: error: '.class' expected
     Multiplication m =new Multiplication(int one; int two); 
                                              ^
Calculator.java:61: error: ';' expected
     Multiplication m =new Multiplication(int one; int two); 
                                                          ^
Calculator.java:64: error: '.class' expected
     Division d =new Division(int one; int two); 
                                  ^
Calculator.java:64: error: ';' expected
     Division d =new Division(int one; int two); 
                                              ^
```

Comment: don't use semicolons but use comma for arguments i.e. instead of `Addition(int one ; int two)` use `Addition(one , two)`

Comment: Could you please give a proper sentence for your question, if anybody else has the same problem how they will identify your question by "plese tell where i am doing mistake" ??

Comment: Start using a IDE to avoid errors like this

Answer (score 1):

```
Addition A =new Addition(int one ; int two);
```

is wrong correct one is :

```
Addition A =new Addition(one , two);
```

this goes for other initialization too.

read [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Call-a-Method-in-Java) specially 6 and 7, to learn more about functions and function call, it is simple visual tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

you already defined the type of 'one' and 'two':

```
int one =input.nextInt();
int two=input.nextInt();
```

So you don't need to redefine it in the parameters list when you invoke a new object. So it is ok when you just write e.g.:

```
Addition A =new Addition(one,two);
```

or

```
Subtraction s =new Subtraction(one, two);
```

also the parameters list is comma separated. I already fixed it in the code brackets above.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple errors here
1.As specified remove semicolon (;) while creating objects of Addition, Subtraction, etc. classes in the main method switch case.
i.e.do the following for all the cases

```
 Addition A =new Addition(one,two);
```

2.You are creating primitive one and two twice in the main method. Just keep it only once. 
Keep variable declaration in the beginning as int one; int two;String choice

Change the code to

```
one =input.nextInt();//remove int in the beginning
two=input.nextInt();//remove int in the beginning
choice = input.nextLine();
```

3.You need to declare "Add", "Sub", "Div", "Mul" in the switch case.
A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class Addition
{
public Addition(int x , int y)
{
 int sum;
 int one = x;
 int two = y;
 sum =x+y;
 System.out.println("Addition of Number: " +sum);
 }
 }

 class Subtraction{
 public  Subtraction(int x ,int y){
 int sub;
 int one = x;
 int two = y;
 sub =x-y;
 System.out.println("Subtraction of Number: " +sub);
 }
 }

 class Multiplication
 {
       public  Multiplication(int x ,int y){
  int mul;
  int one = x;
  int two = y;
  mul =x*y;
  System.out.println("Multiplication of Numbers: " +mul);
  }
  } 

 class Division{
  public  Division(int x , int y){
  int div;
  int one = x;
  int two = y;
  div = x/y;
  System.out.println("Division of Numbers: " +div);
  }
  }
  public class Calculator
       {
       public static void main(String args[]){
       int one;
       int two;
       String choice;

       System.out.print("Enter Choice Add / Sub / Mul / Div");

       Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
       choice = input1.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Enter numbers to calculate:");
       one =input1.nextInt();
       two=input1.nextInt();
       input1.close();
       System.out.println("Your First Number =" +one);
       System.out.println("Your Second Number =" +two);
       System.out.println("Your choice="+choice);

       final String Add = "Add";
       final String Sub = "Sub";
       final String Mul = "Mul";
       final String Div = "Div";

       switch(choice){
       case Add:      
       Addition A =new Addition(one ,two); 
       break;
       case Sub:      
       Subtraction s =new Subtraction(one,two); 
       break;
       case Mul:      
       Multiplication m =new Multiplication(one,two); 
       break;
       case Div:      
       Division d =new Division(one,two); 
       break;
       default:
       System.out.println("Wrong Choice"); 
       break;
               }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the type when calling the constructor.
The list of parameter is comma separated.

```
Addition A =new Addition(one,two);
```